# python vipscc in celery Missing argument

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, celery

Im trying to write a celery task for processing large tif files. From past experience Ive found vipscc uses less memory than pil to process/resize tif's so id like to use that module. The problem is that when i try to import vipscc inside a celery task excuted by a worker i get this message:

fatal Python error: can't initialise module vips
vipsmodule: Missing argument for -c

Ive tried executing the script from the shell outside of a celery worker and it works fine

Im totally stumped I can't even find out what -c is for, has anyone got any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

ok, ive realised this only happens if im running celery in Debug mode. outside of this it works fine